# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.pzh.code.archyonix.service.impl.db1.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.pzh.code.chion.service.impl.db1.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.pzh.code.chion.repository.db1.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pzh.code.chion.repository.db1.UserRepository' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1

User.java

```
package com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1;

import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "cb41477_chion", name = "users")
@Data
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "rub")
    private Integer rub = 0;

    @Column(name = "onix")
    private Integer onix = 0;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Role> roles;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private Vote votes;


}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.pzh.code.chion.repository.db1;

import com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String name);
    User findByEmail(String email);
    Boolean existsByUsername(String name);
    //Boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
package com.pzh.code.chion.service.impl.db1;

import com.pzh.code.chion.repository.db1.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1.Role;
import com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1.Status;
import com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1.User;
import com.pzh.code.chion.repository.db1.RoleRepository;
import com.pzh.code.chion.service.db1.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public User register(User user) {
        Role roleUser = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");
        List<Role> userRoles = new ArrayList<>();
        userRoles.add(roleUser);

        user.setPassword("{bcrypt}"+passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(userRoles);
        user.setStatus(Status.ACTIVE);

        User registeredUser = userRepository.save(user);

        log.info("IN register - user: {} successfully registered", registeredUser);

        return registeredUser;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public User save(User user) {
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        log.info("IN save - user: {} successfully saved", savedUser);

        return savedUser;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        List<User> result = userRepository.findAll();
        log.info("IN getAll - {} users found", result.size());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        User result = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        log.info("IN findByUsername - user: {} found by username: {}", result, username);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        User result = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        log.info("IN findByEmail - user: {} found by email: {}", result, email);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Long id) {
        User result = userRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);

        if (result == null) {
            log.warn("IN findById - no user found by id: {}", id);
            return null;
        }

        log.info("IN findById - user: {} found by id: {}", result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
        log.info("IN delete - user with id: {} successfully deleted");
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
package com.pzh.code.chion.service.db1;

import com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1.User;

import java.util.List;
public interface UserService {

    User register(User user);

    User save(User user);

    List<User> getAll();

    User findByUsername(String username);
    User findByEmail(String email);

    User findById(Long id);

    void delete(Long id);
}
```

SpringDataBaseConfig.java

```
package com.pzh.code.chion.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager"
)
public class SpringDataBaseConfig {
        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManager() {
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                        = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
                em.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
                em.setPackagesToScan(
                        new String[] { "com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1" });

                HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                        = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
                em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
                HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
                properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
                properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

                return em;
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean
        public DataSource primaryDataSource() {

                DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                        = new DriverManagerDataSource();
                dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
                dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
                dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
                dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

                return dataSource;
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager() {

                JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                        = new JpaTransactionManager();
                transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                        primaryEntityManager().getObject());
                return transactionManager;
        }

}
```

SpringMGDataBaseConfig.java

```
package com.pzh.code.chion.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.pzh.code.chion.model.db2",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mgEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "mgTransactionManager"
)
public class SpringMGDataBaseConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mgEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(mgDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[] { "com.pzh.code.chion.model.db2" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource mgDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getProperty("spring.mg-datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.mg-datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.mg-datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.mg-datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager mgTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                mgEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

i tried to:

@Component

@Service

@Repository

etc... More than 10 posts fixing a problem like my problem

The problem appeared after I connected the second database using this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository is not discoverable as you are specifying another root classpath.
In your @EnableJpaRepositories configuration change the base package from :

```
basePackages = "com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1"
```

to

```
basePackages = "com.pzh.code.chion.repository.db1"
```

same for the second datasource, in which you are again specifying the entity/models directory instead of the actual Repositories.

Comment: still the same error(

Comment: you need to set the class package name. Sorry my bad i copied the service one. Try this : basePackages = "com.pzh.code.chion.repository.db1", i am editing also the answer

Comment: P.S 1 more error Error creating bean with name 'shopRepository' defined in com.pzh.code.chion.repository.db1.ShopRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SpringDataBaseConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.pzh.code.chion.shop.Shop

Comment: The specific entity is not under the entities package you are passing to entity Manager. You are scanning only com.pzh.code.chion.model.db1 and com.pzh.code.chion.model.db2 , so either move the Shop entity into one of these packages or pass the package com.pzh.code.chion.shop to each entity manager required on the setPackagesToScan array.